# div popup when there is new updates available

Tags: javascript, jquery, notifications

I've implemented RSS Feed for my application . But , I want that there should be a new updates like Facebook new notification arrives while you are logging on, I mean it depends on user he/she want to see that notification or not.

So , I just want that kind of div appearance . Is there any plugin for that in javascript/jquery?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called *long polling*.
Basically, your client javascript requests the update from the server, but the server keeps the connection open and answers not until update data is available.
This is the most gentle way of doing this, but the implementation depends on your server side framework/language.
See this link for a good introdcution: http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery

The other option you have is setting a timer in javascript and poll every once in a while the server for updates.

Comment: I've developed the server side as well as client side script.I have data from server .I just want the appearance of div , when there is new updates like in Facebook new notification arrives ,nothing else.